# Integrate the infinit scroll with masonry plugin and loading data from MYSQL database

Tags: php, scroll, jquery-masonry

can somebody explain me what i`m doing wrong? I try to integrate the infinit scroll with a masonry layout and loading content from my database.
I want to load pictures from my database on scroll down with a limit of 15 pictures.

The masonory layout is working fine, but i don`t know what is the problem with the infinite scroll.

This is what i have untill now.

HTML CODE

```
<div id="container">

    <?php

    $sql_res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_res))
        {
    $image_name=$row['image_name'];
    $id=$row['id'];

    ?>

<div class="box">


<a href="content.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" ><img src="/content/<?php echo   
$image_name; ?>"></a>

</div>

<?php } ?>

</div>

<nav id="page-nav">
<a href="#"></a>
</nav>
```

JS CODE FOR MASONRY

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>

<script >
$(document).ready(function() {

// Initialize Masonry
$('#container').masonry({
}).imagesLoaded(function() {
    $(this).masonry('reload');
});

$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
  nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.box',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
    });
  }
);

});

</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example HTML, you're missing the appropriate infinite scroll setup.

```
    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
```

This part of the code establishes what URL should be grabbed to load the next content. Your example is blank. You need to put in `<nav id="page-nav"><a href="#"></a></nav>` a valid URL for the infinite scroll jquery plugin to access. When it does, it will look at that page's content to append to the current page. You've appropriately configured it to look at the `.box`, but you don't have a page two to look at!

See: [Infinite Scroll | jQuery plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)